# Unable to ping some switches

Tags: cisco-catalyst

[image: switch topology]

I have this situation:

- all switches have the same vtp domain;
- vtp is either transparent or on off mode;
- SW5 is the root bridge;
- all switches are visible when i execute "sh cdp neighbors";
- the ping is not successful between SW1 and the 3 switches on the right side of the diagram

[image: ping success]

Can somebody help me on that please

Answer (score 0):

Many switches do not respond first icmp packet (first ping)

You need send 2 or more ICMP packets to the switch

Comment: This answer would be better as a comment asking to confirm that the asker is doing multiple pings. It's probably unlikely that someone is sending exactly one ICMP package to decide on pingability.